# Why are timestamps in my GCloud logs are truncated to seconds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I output log records from my GAE application in JSON format. Everything is parsed well except that timestamps are shown with milliseconds truncated:

[image]

I do not supply `timestamp` field with my JSON payload and expect it will be automatically set to current time with nanosecond precision as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry). Apparently this does not this happen as I see only integer value of seconds. Why?

I am also noticing that some standard log categories (nginx metrics, readiness checks) also lack precision occasionally:

[image]

The frequency of this issue is much higher than expected from ranomly getting zeroes from milliseconds.

What can be wrong with my configuration that causes these two issues?

Comment: This [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129492503) might be related to your question - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129492503

Comment: Yep @AlexG, it looks exactly like my issue :-(